# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytorch3d' - Simplified Disco Diffusion

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, disco

I was running this Google Colab today everything was working fine but eventually I starting getting these errors in the Set Up Environment. I can't find a fix. Any help would be appreciated let me know if I need to provide more info.

Here's a link to the colab: https://colab.research.google.com/github/entmike/disco-diffusion-1/blob/main/Simplified_Disco_Diffusion.ipynb

````
 Google Drive already mounted.
✅ Disco Diffusion root path will be "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/disco-diffusion-1"
Google Colab detected.
 Pulling updates from GitHub...

M   download_models.sh
M   examples/docker/disco-file.sh
M   examples/docker/disco.sh
M   examples/docker/interactive.sh
M   examples/docker/unittest.sh
M   examples/linux/configfile.sh
M   examples/linux/simple.sh
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Already up to date.

 Upgrading pyyaml...
 Installing pip requirements...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-4fe875dbbe21> in <module>()
     70 # Import DD helper modules
     71 sys.path.append(PROJECT_DIR)
---> 72 import dd, dd_args
     73 
     74 # Unsure about these:

1 frames
/content/gdrive/MyDrive/disco-diffusion-1/disco_xform_utils.py in <module>()
      3 
      4 # import pytorch3dlite.pytorch3dlite as p3d
----> 5 from pytorch3d import renderer
      6 from midas import utils as midas_utils
      7 from PIL import Image

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytorch3d'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ```
````

Answer (score 1):

I've opened an issue with the author of the repo ([here](https://github.com/entmike/disco-diffusion-1/issues/7)).

In the meantime, open the "Set Up Environment" cell and update the section under "if is_colab" like so:

```
#Upgrade pyyaml if in Colab
if is_colab:
    print(f' checking out specific commit...')
    for cmd in ['git clean -df', f'git reset --hard 3fc1dddb043f7f814db49fe951b4abb7eebd22fd', f'git log -1']:
      gitresults = subprocess.run(f'{cmd}'.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode("utf-8")
      print(f'{gitresults}')
    print(f' Upgrading pyyaml...')
    subprocess.run(f'pip install --upgrade pyyaml --quiet'.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode("utf-8")
    print(f' Installing pip requirements...')
    subprocess.run(f'pip install -r colab-requirements.txt --quiet'.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode("utf-8")
```

what this does is it reverts the last commit which appears to have broken things.

Just re-run the cell (and the ones after)... it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed now.  Thanks for reporting it!